# Make a smaller array from a larger one based on input size java

Tags: java, arrays

If there is a better way to do this i will be happy to listen. I want to create an array with the size of the user input. At the moment the only way i can all the user to enter data into the array. But i want to make the method allow for finding the median so i can't have those extra numbers even if they are zeros.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    static double total;
    static String nums;
    static String[] numsa;
    static double[] numda = {5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5,5};
    static int size;
    static Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.print("Please input data with a space between each digit: ");
        nums = s.nextLine();
        numsa = nums.split("\\s+");
        size = numsa.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            total += (Double.parseDouble(numsa[i]));
        }

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
                numda[i] = Double.parseDouble(numsa[i]);
                System.out.println("Num Double Array[" + i + "] = " + numda[i]); 
        }   
        System.out.println("Total: " + total);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Why dont you just ignore 0's

Comment: The median would require me to find the middle of the array the 0's would mess with that and the user could enter a 0 so i would like to not ignore them.

Comment: Note: You can merge those two for loops as a small optimization. This also allows you to only parse each double once.

Comment: Have you considered using a `List` instead of an array?  Then you wouldn't have to manage the size yourself.

Comment: Alternatively, keep a length of data and ignore array values that are past the length value...  Having a buffer doesn't mean you have to use the whole thing.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're accomplishing with this code.  You claim you want the median, but I don't see why you need the `numda` array at all.  Could you elaborate what you're attempting to do?

Answer (score 2):

After getting `size` you can do

```
numda = new double[size];
```

to create an array of length `size`.

See the docs at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html.